# Averaging large data set with bins in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a large (~100GB) data set `xs` of structured numpy arrays `x` where I want to bin each by a property `p1` and want to find the mean and standard deviation of property `p2` in each bin. My method shown below works, but is quite slow. Is there any faster/more numpythonic way to do this? I can't fit the whole dataset in memory, but I do have lots of cores, so a nice way to parallelise it would also be nice.

```py
nbins=30
bin_edges=np.linspace(0,1,nbins) 

N, p2_total, means_p2, stds_p2 = np.zeros((4,nbins))      

for x in xs_generator():
    p1s = x['p1']
    p2s = x['p2']

    which_bin=np.digitize(p1s,bins=bin_edges)

    for this_bin,bin_edge in enumerate(bin_edges):
        these_p1s    = p1s[which_bin==this_bin]
        these_p2s    = p2s[which_bin==this_bin]

        N[this_bin]          += np.size(these_p1s)
        p2_total[this_bin]   += np.sum(these_p2s)
        p2sq_total[this_bin] += np.sum(these_p2s**2)

means_p2 = p2_total/N
stds_p2  = np.sqrt(p2sq_total/N**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

- you should use np.histogram:

  ```
  N, binDump = np.histogram( p1s, bins=bin_edges )
  p2_total, binDump = np.histogram( p1s, bins=bin_edges, weights=p2s )
  p2sq_total, binDump = np.histogram( p1s, bins=bin_edges, weights=p2s**2 )

  means_p2 = p2_total/N
  stds_p2  = np.sqrt(p2sq_total/N**2)
  ```

like this you avoid the loop, you just re-write the histogram function :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very neat. Even though I expect it to perform faster, it actually takes almost exactly the same time. It also gives slightly different answers, but I haven't checked which one incurs the bigger error.

Comment: disappointed by the performance, sorry. You should parallelize over the 'xs' loop. To do so look at http://www.perrygeo.com/parallelizing-numpy-array-loops-with-cython-and-mpi.html . It is not a proper answer, but I hope you can find something useful